# Selecting the maximum value for a factor in base R

Tags: r

I am trying to find out the maximum price for each of the carat factor levels in diamonds dataset:

```
diamonds[,'carat']<-factor(diamonds[,'carat'])
df<-with(diamonds, tapply(diamonds$price, diamonds$carat, max))
```

The output is a data frame of just two columns. I would like my df to contain all other columns in the dataset. In addition, I would like the table to retain the names of the columns. Now the two rows in df are 'row names' and 'x'. Thanks.

Comment: diamonds dataset has about 10 columns( carat, cut, color, clarity etc.). I would like to retain all other columns values that correspond to the already selected (carat, price). For my purpose, if the price for a carat level has more than one maximum value, it does not matter which row is selected.

Comment: Do you need the row that has the max value for price per each carat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try `ave` if you need to a create a new column in the existing dataset

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
diamonds$Max <- with(diamonds,ave(price, carat,FUN= max))
```

Or if you need the row that has the `max` value of 'price' for each 'carat' group

```
library(dplyr)
res1 <- diamonds %>% 
             group_by(carat) %>%
             slice(which.max(price))
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
res2 <- as.data.table(diamonds)[,.SD[which.max(price)] , carat]
```

Or

```
library(sqldf)
nm1 <- setdiff(names(diamonds), 'price')
nm1[6] <- paste0("[",(nm1[6]),"]")
res3 <- sqldf(sprintf('select %s,
                       max(price) as price
                       from diamonds
                       group by carat',
                       toString(nm1)))
```

Or using `base R`

```
res4 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(diamonds, diamonds$carat), 
                  function(x) x[which.max(x$price),]))
```

If we need all the `max` values instead of `which.max` we can use `Price==max(Price)` in the above the solutions.  Also, a solution based on `ave` would be

```
res5 <- diamonds[with(diamonds, ave(price, carat, FUN=max)==price),]
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. It works, but I need a separate data frame, so I can box plot the max price across carat levels. As I see it it means that I need just one price value for each carat level.

Comment: @Vasile You can assign the result from `dplyr/data.table` to a new object. i.e. `res <- diamonds %>% group_by(carat) %>% filter(price==max(price))`

Comment: @acrun. For some reason I can not install dplyr or data.table. So I am trying to do this in R base. I tried you last solution, but I am not sure what output it gives me. It has 311 observations and some of the carat levels are repeating. Since I have 273 unique carat levels, I would like a dataset that has a all original columns with 273 rows selected by unique carat level and maximum price (as I said if there are two maximum prices, I do not care which one is selected).

Comment: @Vasile The dplyr/data.table solutions give 273 unique rows, but in the `ave`, it gives 311 rows as we are taking all the `max` values per group.

Comment: @arkun I see now. Is there a way to filter the ave output further to the 273 unique rows?

Comment: @Vasile try `do.call(rbind,lapply(split(diamonds, diamonds$carat), function(x) x[which.max(x$price),]))`